# Super poner un marker sobre un mapa con layer

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo un mapa con este[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero que al darle clic en un marker, aparezca un layer gris opaco, pero el marker se superposicione, algo así como esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El layer lo puse con css

```
<div id="map" style="width:100%; height:93vh;"></div>
<div ng-show="vm.show" onClick="vm.show=false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top:0px; bottom:0px; background:#000000; opacity:0.5; width:100%; height:100%;  color:#FFFFFF; z-index:10;">
```

Y lo mando a llamar con este evento:

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
                _markers[this.id].setZIndex(10000);
                vm.show = true;
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

`setZIndex` establece el nivel dentro del mapa, no se relaciona con las propiedades CSS y como el overlay que usas esta por fuera del mapa queda debajo del mismo. Ten en cuenta que el mapa funciona en un canvas, no un elemento como tal.-

Para la solución o bien pones el overlay en el KML, o puedes intentar este truco: cambiar `src` de la imagen cuando hace click modificando la `url` y esa a `url` de imagen diferente cambiarle el `z-index` via CSS..

CSS

```
img[src*="overlay"] {
  z-index: 11; /* al menos 1 mas que el overlay */
}
```

Angular JS (en el controller deberas injectar el $scope para poder usar $apply)

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
  this.setIcon('icono.png?overlay'); // aqui el truco
  $scope.$apply(function () {
    vm.show = true;
  });      
});
```

Luego en la rutina donde se quita el overlay

```
  this.setIcon('icono.png'); // vuelta a al nivel normal
  vm.show = false;           // usa $apply si esta fuera del ciclo de digest.
```

Comment: Te falta inyectar `$scope` y usar `$scope.$apply` en el evento `click` ya que estos ocurren fuera del ciclo digest de angular por lo que la llamada a `$apply` es necesaria.

Comment: @devconcept recién veo el mensaje y tienes razón, me enfoqué en lo otro. lo voy a editar pronto